# Different Header/Footer on Different Pages

Tags: google-docs

How do I make this:

- Pages 2–14: Header A + Footnote
- Pages 15–25: Header B + Footnote
- Pages 26–30: Header C + Footnote

And so on.

I’m trying to write a story and have lots of chapters, and I want to include each chapter name in the header of that chapter.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to insert a section, to split your document content in two or more sections. Then you could customize each section settings, including the header/footer for each section.

This is feature added after this question was posted, I think.

On the Google Docs editor, click the Help menu, the on the search box type `section`. The help will suggest you the related menu options.

Answer (score -1):

Custom headers/footers per every page are not supported. You can have a custom header/footer only on the first page of your document - the rest of headers/footers will be cloned.

[image: 5]

Best you can do is to set custom page margins in **File > Page setup...** and then **<kbd>TAB</kbd>** it out manually.

[image: 6]